Is it possible to use Singleton with Tippy in a React .map function? If so, how?
I have a React component built to render a row of buttons, which are generated by using a .map function to create them all from a passed-in array. I have set up a Tippy tooltip for each button using the NPM package @tippyjs/react, and they all work correctly individually. I am now trying to implement the Singleton functionality so the transition is smooth between the tooltips for each button in the row.
The Singletop section of the NPM page for @tippyjs/react (https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react?tab=readme-ov-file#-usesingleton) states to do the following:
import Tippy, {useSingleton} from '@tippyjs/react';

function App() {
  const [source, target] = useSingleton();

  return (
    <>
      {/* This is the tippy that gets used as the singleton */}
      <Tippy singleton={source} delay={500} />

      {/* These become "virtual" */}
      <Tippy content="Hello" singleton={target}>
        <button>Reference</button>
      </Tippy>
      <Tippy content="Bye" singleton={target}>
        <button>Reference</button>
      </Tippy>
    </>
  );
}

I have my code set up as follows:
import Tippy, {useSingleton} from '@tippyjs/react';

export default function TrackedShow({...}){
    const [source, target] = useSingleton();
    return(
        <>
            ...
                <div className='tracked-show-season-episodes-container'>
                    <Tippy singleton={source} delay={50}/>
                    {trackedShowSeason.episodeObjectIds.map((episode, episodeIndex)=>{
                        return(
                            <form className='tracked-show-season-episode-container' id={`episode-${episode._id}`} key={`episode-${episode._id}`} onSubmit={handleToggleEpisodeWatched}>
                                <Tippy
                                    singleton={target}
                                    theme={'tippy-theme'}
                                    animation={'scale'}
                                    plugins={[followCursor, animateFill, sticky]}
                                    followCursor={'vertical'}
                                    sticky={true}
                                    placement={'bottom'}
                                    hideOnClick={false}
                                    content=
                                        {hoveredEpisodeTile && (hoveredEpisodeTile===episode._id) &&
                                            <div className='tippy-content'>
                                                <p className='tippy-title'>Episode Title:</p>
                                                <p className='tippy-episode-title'>"{episode.episodeTitle}"</p>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                >
                                    <button
                                        className={'tracked-show-season-episode-button '+((watchedEpisodes.includes(episode._id)) ? 'watched' : 'unwatched')}
                                        type='submit' value={episode._id}
                                        onMouseOver={handleEpisodeTileMouseOver}
                                        onMouseOut={handleEpisodeTileMouseOut}>
                                        {episode.episodeNumber ? `Episode ${episode.episodeNumber}` : 'Special'}
                                    </button>
                                </Tippy>

                            </form>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            ...
        </>
    );

I am at a loss for how to correctly implement Singleton in this case, if it's even possible, because I can't find an example online of Singleton being used within a .map function. The @tippyjs/react docs I pasted above show Singleton being used on hard-coded buttons. This is not possible in my case because the buttons are generated dynamically when a user loads a page.
Is there any way to use Singleton within a .map function? It doesn't seem to work regardless of where I place the <Tippy singleton={source} delay={50}/> element, and I can't think of a way to cause the .map function to generate a <Tippy singleton={source} delay={50}/> element before generating all the buttons based on the array passed into it.
